# How to check if two properties are equal to another object's properties in Joi?

Tags: javascript, joi

Is it possible to make `Joi` check if `source.listId === destination.listId && source.index === destination.index` then return an error?

My example:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  source: Joi.object().keys({
    listId: Joi.string()
      .length(24)
      .required()
      .when('...destination.index', {
        is: Joi.equal(Joi.ref('index')),
        then: Joi.disallow(Joi.ref('...destination.listId'))
      }),
    index: Joi.number()
      .integer()
      .positive()
      .required()
  }),
  destination: Joi.object().keys({
    listId: Joi.string()
      .length(24)
      .required(),
    index: Joi.number()
      .integer()
      .positive()
      .required()
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I had to validate `source.index` property with `when` as well:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  source: Joi.object().keys({
    listId: Joi.string()
      .length(24)
      .required()
      .when('...destination.index', {
        is: Joi.equal(Joi.ref('index')),
        then: Joi.disallow(Joi.ref('...destination.listId'))
      }),
    index: Joi.number()
      .integer()
      .positive()
      .required()
      .when('...destination.listId', {
        is: Joi.equal(Joi.ref('listId')),
        then: Joi.disallow(Joi.ref('...destination.index'))
      })
  }),
  destination: Joi.object().keys({
    listId: Joi.string()
      .length(24)
      .required(),
    index: Joi.number()
      .integer()
      .positive()
      .required()
  })
});
```